# ActionScript 3 JEOPARDY flash game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to make an AS3 JEOPARDY like flash game, but I can't figure out how to feed the published swf with an external sheet containing questions - xml or txt or something similar... Could somebody help me with some useful ideas please? Or some of you pros - if you feel like it - you could even elaborate and provide a more detailed description :)
thank you all in advance

Comment: looks like you got some great feedback to get you off to a good start -- keep us posted so we can see the results.  I've thought about doing something similar but keep getting sidetracked!  good luck.

Comment: Hi there. Questions that are discursive are off-topic here - there are too many possible answers. It's best to show the code you're working on, and ask a question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Use [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html) to load external data into your swf.

And don't use XML, better take JSON format: faster to load, easier to read by your program

(with XML you often have to read and then transform data, with JSON you just load and are done).

Also, I've just remembered that the [ActionScript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565928527.do) book comes with a [Jeopardy flash game](http://www.moock.org/asdg/codedepot/) example.

[image]

Comment: Depends on situation with the XML vs JSON. JSON will always be quicker to load since it is a much simpler format, but it is much easier to write and read XML than JSON. If the questions have any chance of being set by a non-dev, it might be worth using XML over JSON

Comment: Especially for a non dev or newbie my advice to use JSON over XML is priceless ;-)

Comment: @JoshJanusch unless you can show proof and not just your feelings on XML being faster you shouldn't post that it is.

Comment: @The_asMan Reread what I said. Not once did I say XML was faster; in fact, I explicitly said JSON would load quicker since it should, in theory, always be smaller. I was just pointing out that XML is generally easier to read, especially for non-technical people and that the best choice may not actually be the one which is faster to load and parse (JSON)

Comment: hey guys. I'll have to do some research on JSON, cuz I don't have a clue what it is :) 
ALEX thanks for the useful links, but pls I need better direction to where the Jeopardy game source files are located. I can't find them :(

Comment: http://www.moock.org/asdg/codedepot/chapter-examples/chap01/quiz.fla and of course in the book.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use a web service that you host, as opposed to an XML document that's actually out on the Internet.  At least when you're using MXML, web services tend to be pretty easy to use in AS3.  Using a web service, instead of an XML page or text page or something, would make it a little less trivial for people to cheat (especially if the web method requires that a password be supplied as an argument).

Answer (score 0):

external meaning? You have to access a saved questions and answers to the games? If that's the case then xml is great for it. You can visit 
    http://www.flashgameu.com/ it contains that tutorial and a sample for a question with timers. And look for the book source files.